# backbone.js trigger events in render()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am tying to some events in the `render` function of backbone.js, more specfically a `click`, however, I cannot get it to work.

I have a similar (but very simplified) set-up to:

```
App.ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({

className: 'title_products_tab',
el: $('.title_products_tab'),

events: {
    'click .product_list .edit_product' : 'edit',
```

For the events section of my backbone view. Down within the render function I wish to trigger the bound `.edit_product` `click` event:

```
render: function(){
        console.log($._data( $('.title_products_tab .product_list .edit_product')[0], "events" ));
        $('.title_products_tab .product_list .edit_product').trigger('click');
```

Which does not work, the `_data` for the element is undefined, however, I know the event does work because the rest of my view functions accordingly. I just cannot seem to trigger events in `render` or anywhere else on startup.

I thought:

```
this.trigger('click .product_list .edit_product');
```

Would work however, again no luck.

I also heard about `bindAll` but I heard that it was not a good idea to use this.

So how do I, or rather when do I, trigger startup events for my backbone view?

Comment: When are you calling your render method? In the initialize method?

Comment: @Loamhoof Indeed, in the init method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you may find this interesting (note: Backbone's code):

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
  this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
  this._configure(options || {});
  this._ensureElement();
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  this.delegateEvents();
};
```

Especially the last part. The events are bound **after** the initialize method is called, so after your render method is called. The events are not bound yet.

(I guess you could manually call `delegateEvents` if you really need to do it the way you do)

Comment: Well I guess you could simply call the method yourself: `this.edit()`. Change one line of code for another, doesn't seem such a bad deal ;)

Comment: That is a good idea though it attaches to a product list and if that list is 1 in size I select the only entry for that list for the user, doing that pogrammably via internal coding would not be nice for me; I am currently using backbone as a means to standardise the front end of an already existing form; ah, I'll just do the delegate, thanks :)